# NSMutableURLRequest sending 2 times while using NSURLSession

Tags: objective-c, asp.net-web-api, nsurlsession, nsmutableurlrequest, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am using `NSMutableURLRequest` is working correct when I am using

```
- (void)postAsynchronousOnQueue:(NSOperationQueue*)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))completionHandler {
    NSURLRequest* request = [self createPostRequest];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
-(NSURLRequest*)createPostRequest {
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[HttpRequest requestWithRelativePath:@"/photo"] toNSMutableURLRequest];
             [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
             [request setHTTPBody:[self encodeParamsForUpload]];
             return request;  
}
```

But the issue is when my app is in background mode it won't work.

Here is my `HttpRequest` class method:

```
+(id)requestWithRelativePath:(NSString*)docpath {
    return [[HttpRequest alloc] initWithRelativePath:docpath server:server username:email password:password];
}  
-(id)initWithRelativePath:(NSString*)docpath server:(NSString*)server username:(NSString*)username password:(NSString*)password {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        docpath = [docpath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        _request = [self createRequestWithDocPath:docpath server:server username:username password:password];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest*)createRequestWithDocPath:(NSString*)docpath server:(NSString*)server username:(NSString*)username password:(NSString*)password {
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@%@", server, docpath]];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:120.0];
    if ((username != nil) && (password != nil)){
        NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password];
        NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [self base64Encoding:authData]];
        [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    }
    return request;
}
```

From, stack overflow I found `NSURLSession` to work API calls in background. So I used `NSURLSession`. Here is my updated code which I did:

```
- (void)postAsynchronousOnQueue:(NSOperationQueue*)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))completionHandler {
    NSURLRequest* request = [self createPostRequest];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
-(NSURLRequest*)createPostRequest {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[HttpRequest requestWithRelativePath:@"/photo"] toNSMutableURLRequest];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[self encodeParamsForUpload]];
    //Create task
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        //Handle your response here
        [[NSURLSession sharedSession]invalidateAndCancel];
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
    return request; 
}
```

But, when I am using `NSURLSession` the request is sending two times I already put the breakpoints in `NSMutableURLRequest`line but it call only once.

Please, help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would avoid creating a new `NSURLSession` for each request. I would create it once and reuse it for each request. Or just use `sharedSession`. I'd also remove the invalidation of the `NSURLSession`, on the presumption that you might use it again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createPostRequest` is creating a request and submitting it via `NSURLSession`. But it also returns the `NSURLRequest` and `postAsynchronousOnQueue` proceeds to submit it again, this time through the deprecated `NSURLConnection`.

Remove the `NSURLConnection` code and just rely upon `NSURLSession` to issue the request.

---

For example:

```
- (void)postAsynchronousOnQueue:(NSOperationQueue*)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *, NSURLResponse*, NSError*))completionHandler {
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[HttpRequest requestWithRelativePath:@"/photo"] toNSMutableURLRequest];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[self encodeParamsForUpload]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        //Handle your response here
        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            completionHandler(data, response, error);
        }];
    }];

    [dataTask resume]; 
}
```